# How to open and load a JSON file inside a .zip archive?

Tags: python, json, zip, python-3.10

So I have a python script I run in a directory which contains .zip files and these zip files all have JSON files which I want to load. With my current method I get an error of 'No such file or directory' when I try to 'open(filename)' I assume this is because namelist() doesn't actually enter the .zip directory. How can I load the JSON file inside this zip archive once I confirm that it is indeed a .zip archive?

```
import zipfile
import json
import os

myList = []

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
    if f.endswith('.zip'):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(f) as myzip:
            for filename in myzip.namelist():
                if filename.endswith('.json'):
                    g = open(filename)
                    data = json.load(g)
                    #do stuff with g and myList
```

Comment: `open(filename)` should be `myzip.open(filename)`

Comment: You're trying to open a regular file, not the file in the zip archive.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much sir! Your explanation makes sense and it worked!